# Failed to get containers "/" in cAdvisor Docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, cadvisor, ubuntu-22.04

I runned cadvisor docker with this command

```
docker run \
--volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
--volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw  \
--volume=/sys:/sys:ro  \
--volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro  \
--volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro  \
--publish=8080:8080  --detach=true \
--name=cadvisor \
gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:v0.36.0
```

I can run without getting error:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                       NAMES
a0aa3cc8d5f2   gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:v0.36.0   "/usr/bin/cadvisor -…"   48 seconds ago   Up 48 seconds (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   cadvisor
```

When I go to **localhost:8080**, I give me this error messages 
**failed to get container "/" with error: unable to find data in memory cache**

I tried with **sudo docker run** still same error. 

How can I fix this? Is this docker related or cadvisor?


 Here is my system info:
**OS** : Ubuntu 22.04 
**Docker Info**:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
  userxattr: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc version: v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  rootless
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-40-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 12
 Total Memory: 13.51GiB
 Name: ubuntu-yan
 ID: EHQF:VYEN:4YZV:GQ6C:THPI:5J3F:A5JS:OLR7:H4QN:Q5Q5:EATM:2RXR
 Docker Root Dir: /home/yanpaing/.local/share/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: No cpuset support
WARNING: No io.weight support
WARNING: No io.weight (per device) support
WARNING: No io.max (rbps) support
WARNING: No io.max (wbps) support
WARNING: No io.max (riops) support
WARNING: No io.max (wiops) support
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because old cadvisor version don't support "recent" cgroups version.

I upgraded to fix the issue.

## Troubleshooting tips

Use `docker logs`  to retrieve cadvisor logs. Mine showed errors like:

```
W0107 09:20:00.064502  1 container.go:526] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/cups.service": \
failed to parse memory.usage_in_bytes - open /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/cups.service/memory.usage_in_bytes: \
no such file or directory, continuing to push stats
```